# how to insert and display fetched values in the same checkbox in php?

Tags: php, foreach

It displays menu_name as tree and i appended checkbox with it.
    after that i inserted checkbox value into database with menu_name.
    if the menu_name(tree) already inserted.within the same checkbox 
    i need to display the checkbox as checked.So i fetching checkbox values from db as true(t)
    and displays as checked inside the existing for loop but it looping 3 more times again so it displays as the following:

[image]

This my code below:

```
           foreach($data['res'] as $result){ 
                echo "Menu Name:".$result['menu_name'];

            foreach($data['check_res'] as $res_chk) 
            {
                echo $res_chk;
                ?>
                Select view:<input type="checkbox" <?php if($res_chk['view'] = "t"){ echo 'checked';}else{ echo '';} ?> name="view[]">
        <?php
            }   
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: please use '==' instead of '='  Select view:<input type="checkbox" <?php if($res_chk['view'] = "t"){ echo 'checked';}else{ echo '';} ?> name="view[]">

Comment: you have 2 loops, running against the $data result, can you show the structure of $data in full

Comment: yes i changed that.but my problem is when i fetch the values from db it have (t f t) so i need to check the 1st and 3rd checkbox dynamically but inside the same loop it displays again (t f t)(t f t)(t f t)

Comment: I cannot help you without knowing the structure you are looping through, and your code example still looks the same

Comment: @noid when i print_r($data['res']) it displays Array ( [0] => Array ( [menu_code] => 2 [menu_code] => Tree)
  [1] => Array ( [menu_code] => 3 [menu_name] => Land)
  [2] => Array ( [menu_code] => 6 [menu_name] => Nature))   And when i print this print_r($data['check_res']) it displays Array ( [0] => Array ( [menu_name] => Tree [view] => t )
  [1] => Array ( [menu_name] => Land [view] => f )
  [2] => Array ( [menu_name] => Nature [view] => t ))

Comment: ideally you would merge those two to gether, but if if the keys in each array are corresponding to the same menu item, you can use the array key to reference both arrays in one loop

Comment: no i already merged but it doesn't works because sometime the array $data['res'] will have more menu names but the array $data['check_res'] will contain only db values so the both arrays have sometimes unequal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($data['res'] as $key => $result){ 
            echo "Menu Name:".$result['menu_name'];

            ?>
            Select view:<input type="checkbox" <?php if($data['check_res'][$key] = "t"){ echo 'checked';}else{ echo '';} ?> name="view[]">
    <?php 
    }
```

Comment: yes it working now...! i maked condition with your answer <input type="checkbox" name="view[]" <?php if (!empty($data['check_res'][$key])){
   if(($data['check_res'][$key]]) == "t"){ echo 'checked';}else{ echo '';}} ?> value="<?php echo $result['menu_code']; ?>"  class="minimal">